# Kotlin, Reactive programming : How to consume the value of one function output to another one

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am very new to Project reactor library and reactive programming with Kotlin, and trying to implement functions like `flatmap`, `flatMapIterable`, `subscribe` etc.
Now issue is I am trying to use the o/p of one function into another one using `flatMapIterable`, and after using I am trying to subscribe this, by passing the output of fist function and second one to another function of new class.
Now when I try to use the o/p of function 1, I am unable to see the value, I only see `Mono<>` or `Flux<>`.

Below is code snippet for more explanation

```
var result = employerService.getEmployee("Active") // return value is Mono<GetEmployeeStatusListResult>
result.flatMapIterable(GetEmployeeStatusListResult::emps)
      .flatMap {
          employerService.getUsersById(it.userId) // it is of type GetEmployeeStatusListResult.emps and  value returned from employerService.getUsersById(it.userId) is of type GetUserResult class created 
      }.subscribe {
          aService.createContact(result, it)    
      }
```

Now at line 4 I am getting expected `userId` out of `it.userId`, but when I inspect result at line 6, then I do not get the expected list of values, it just provides me `MonomapFuesable`, with mapper and source.

Can anyone please help me to understand what should I do, as my whole agenda is to pass the calculated value from line 1 and line 4 to line 6 function.
Please ask more question, if I haven't provided the required information, I am very new to this.
Thanks in advance !!

[UPDATE] : I have resolved the issue with the following way : 
```

```
employerService.getEmployee("Active") // return value is Mono<GetEmployeeStatusListResult>
.flatMapIterable(GetEmployeeStatusListResult::emps)
          .flatMap {
              employerService.getUsersById(it.userId).map{x->Pair(it,x)} // it is of type GetEmployeeStatusListResult.emps and  value returned from employerService.getUsersById(it.userId) is of type GetUserResult class created 
          }.subscribe {
              aService.createContact(it.first, it.second)    
          }
```

```

Comment: I think it will help if you list the types returned by each of the variables. At some point an observable is not being returned and that could be the problem.

Comment: @Mahesh edited the code snippet with comment for each line return type,  assuming you are asking for this only

Comment: This is Kotlin, right? RxJS, as its name indicates, is a JavaScript library. Not a Kotlin or Java library. What you're using (Mono, Flux, etc.) are types from the Reactor library. Not from RxJS. Edit your question, change its title and text and remove the RxJS tag: RxJS has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet for correcting me !!
Do you have any suggestions/advice for the above questions, Please share your expertise!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to know for sure from the information supplied above, but I think it looks like the call to `employerService.getUsersById` isn't returning a `Publisher`. From your comments I'm guessing it's returning an actual value, `GetUserResult`, rather than a `Mono`. Below is a mocked up set of classes which show the desired result, I believe. Maybe compare the below to what you've got and see if you can spot a difference?

```
data class Employee(val userId: String)
data class GetEmployeeStatusListResult(val emps: List<Employee>)
data class GetUserResult(val employee: Employee)

class EmployerService {
    fun getEmployee(status: String) = Mono.just(GetEmployeeStatusListResult(listOf(Employee("a"))))
    fun getUsersById(userId: String) = Mono.just(GetUserResult(Employee("a")))
}

fun test() {
    val employerService = EmployerService()
    employerService
            .getEmployee("Active")
            .flatMapIterable(GetEmployeeStatusListResult::emps)
            .flatMap {
                employerService.getUsersById(it.userId)
            }.subscribe {
                // Here "it" is a GetUserResult object
            }
}
```

If, in the `subscribe`, you need both the initial value retrieved from the call to `getEmployee` and also the result of the call to `getUsersById` then you could wrap those two values in a `Pair` as shown below:

```
employerService
        .getEmployee("Active")
        .flatMapIterable(GetEmployeeStatusListResult::emps)
        .flatMap { emp ->
            employerService.getUsersById(emp.userId).map { emp to it }
        }.subscribe {
            // Here "it" is a Pair<Employee, GetUserResult>
        }
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding Pair only but not in subscribe block but before that, I have updated the question with solution under UPDATE section.
Thanks much !!

Answer (score 0):

```
employerService.getEmployee("Active") // return value is Mono<GetEmployeeStatusListResult>
.flatMapIterable(GetEmployeeStatusListResult::emps)
          .flatMap {
              employerService.getUsersById(it.userId).map{x->Pair(it,x)} // it is of type GetEmployeeStatusListResult.emps and  value returned from employerService.getUsersById(it.userId) is of type GetUserResult class created 
          }.subscribe {
              aService.createContact(it.first, it.second)    
          }
```

Adding pair function to fetch both the values and use it in subscribe block !!
Thanks everyone !!